# react-cropper: How to set image and cropper section size

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cropperjs

In my project using react-cropper for image crop section. Here I want a fixed crop size and fixed image size but I can't find the right way to do this. Please give me a solution to solve this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cropper from "react-cropper";
import "cropperjs/dist/cropper.css";
import "./Demo.css";

type Props = {
  LabelName?: string;
};

export const Demo = (props: Props) => {
  const { LabelName } = props;
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [cropData, setCropData] = useState("#");
  const [cropper, setCropper] = useState<any>();

  ......


  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <input type="file" onChange={onChange} />
        <br />
        <Cropper
          zoomOnTouch={false}
          zoomOnWheel={false}
          zoomable={false}
          aspectRatio={finalAspectRatio}
          preview=".img-preview"
          src={image}
          viewMode={1}
          minCropBoxWidth={800}
          minCropBoxHeight={200}
          background={false}
          responsive={true}
          checkOrientation={false}
          onInitialized={(instance) => {
            console.log("instance", instance);
            setCropper(instance);
          }}
          guides={true}
          cropBoxResizable={false}
        />
      </div>

      ......
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

Here added "minCropBoxWidth={800} and minCropBoxHeight={200}" but its not working as expected.

[image]
Here "width: 751px; height: 285.692px; transform: translateY(71.2979px);"
Here the crop-box width is varying but I want width=800px.

so added "aspectRatio={finalAspectRatio}".Its also not working properly.Is there any issue in image section?

Comment: What isn't working as expected? What is the issue? Are there any errors? Please try to provide more details.

Comment: There is no error but I want to add a fixed width and height for the cropper box. The question is edited.

Comment: It seems even the demo linked from the repo doesn't work as expected. I'd suggest filing an issue with the repo's maintainer(s) in github.